# How to add query strings in php for duplicate URL AB text

Tags: php

Now i m using PHP for my work, it has around 20 pages. I need to duplicate all the URLs along with Query String for AB test.

```
Original : www.lorem.com/index.php
Duplicate: www.lorem.com/index.php?custom (Something like that)
```

Thank you team

Answer (score 2):

A good solution could be to use a URL Rewrite scheme in a `.htaccess` document. A solution like the following could work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*)/custom$ /$1-test.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will cause the following to be true:

```
Original  : www.lorem.com/index.php
Duplicate : www.lorem.com/index-test.php (When /custom is appended, this page is shown)
```

Have a look at this for reference on URL Rewriting: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/